# scale.linear() is returning NaN

Tags: d3.js

Im running a simple bar chart using d3.scale.linear() and hardcoding he domain range for this example

I can see in firebug that when aplying attr of width to my div, w_bar appears to be NaN.

Why is that?

```
var w_bar = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 107525233]) //harcoded
    .range(["0px", "290px"]);

var theList = d3.select("#list").selectAll("div")
    .data(myJSON);

theList.enter().append("div")
    .text(function (d) { return d.v; })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", w_bar); // Why NaN?

theList.exit()
    .remove();
```

Here's the jsfiddle:
[http://jsfiddle.net/NAhD9/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/NAhD9/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `w_bar` is Not a Number, and the `width` attribute needs to be a number. Hence, NaN.

If you want your `width` attribute to scale based on the `v` attribute in your `myJSON` object, you should say 
`.attr("width",function (d) {return w_bar(d.v)})`.

This is how scales work in `d3`, they are a function which takes in an argument (some value within the `domain` of the scale) and returns that value transformed to fit into the `range` of your scale.

Updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NAhD9/11/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a function to tell d3 how you want your data to interact with to scale to create an array:

```
.attr("width", function(d){ return w_bar(d.v); })
```

This will take all the `v` attributes from objects making up the `myJSON` array, scale them with `w_bar`, and set the width of their corresponding rectangles equal to that value.